# SQL Query to View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I am trying to turn the following query into a view, however I receive the following execution error:

[image]

Can anyone pinpoint where I am going wrong?

Should look like:

```
Financial Year  VOLUME  # Cases 5mins   # Cases 10mins  # Cases 15mins  # Cases 20mins            
2014/15         1490200      1029             6732            10163        11798    
2015/16         1548700     1143                7286          10693         12338  
etc...
```

Code:

```
 SELECT t1.[Financial Year], t1.[VOLUME], t2.[# Cases 5mins], t3.[# Cases 10mins], t4.[# Cases 15mins], t5.[# Cases 20mins]
FROM 
    (SELECT [Financial Year], CAST(COUNT([Event Number]) AS DECIMAL)  *100 as 'VOLUME' FROM tblCAD 
 WHERE [AO-NonPublicEvent] = 1 AND [Reporting Exclusions] = 0 AND [Reporting Priority] = '1'
GROUP BY [Financial Year]) t1
left join
    (SELECT [Financial Year], CAST(COUNT([Event Number]) AS DECIMAL) as '# Cases 5mins' from tblCAD 
WHERE  [AO-NonPublicEvent] = 1 AND [Reporting Exclusions] = 0 AND CAST([Response Time] AS DECIMAL(9,2))/60 <= 5 AND [Reporting Priority] = '1'
GROUP BY [Financial Year]) t2

ON (t1.[Financial Year] = t2.[Financial Year]) 
left join 
  (SELECT [Financial Year], CAST(COUNT([Event Number]) AS DECIMAL) as '# Cases 10mins' from tblCAD 
WHERE  [AO-NonPublicEvent] = 1 AND [Reporting Exclusions] = 0 AND CAST([Response Time] AS DECIMAL(9,2))/60 <= 10 AND [Reporting Priority] = '1'
GROUP BY [Financial Year]) t3
on (t1.[Financial Year] = t3.[Financial Year])
left join 
  (SELECT [Financial Year], CAST(COUNT([Event Number]) AS DECIMAL) as '# Cases 15mins' from tblCAD 
WHERE  [AO-NonPublicEvent] = 1 AND [Reporting Exclusions] = 0 AND CAST([Response Time] AS DECIMAL(9,2))/60 <= 15 AND [Reporting Priority] = '1'
GROUP BY [Financial Year]) t4
on (t1.[Financial Year] = t4.[Financial Year])
left join 
  (SELECT [Financial Year], CAST(COUNT([Event Number]) AS DECIMAL) as '# Cases 20mins' from tblCAD 
WHERE  [AO-NonPublicEvent] = 1 AND [Reporting Exclusions] = 0 AND CAST([Response Time] AS DECIMAL(9,2))/60 <= 20 AND [Reporting Priority] = '1'
GROUP BY [Financial Year]) t5
on (t1.[Financial Year] = t5.[Financial Year])
```

Comment: It appears that your posted query is not the query that generates the error you posted. In the error message, we can clearly see that single quotes are used to delimit "spacey" column names (which is not valid) and that the first column selected is VOLUME and not [Financial Year]. Until the query you use to define the view executes without error in a SSMS query window, you won't be able to create a view from it.

Comment: That’s @ethan. Did try that, didn’t work :-(

Comment: And thank you @Smor. Sorry may have posed the query where I tried removing the Financial Year to see if it made a difference - which it didn’t. I still receive the same error either way, but good pickup!! Also, I am able to successfully execute in query window- probably why it has me stumped!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code isn't working.  But it can be significantly simplified using conditional aggregation and then it will probably work:

```
SELECT [Financial Year],
       COUNT(*) * 100 as VOLUME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CAST([ Response Time ] AS DECIMAL(9, 2)) / 60 <= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as within_5_minutes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CAST([ Response Time ] AS DECIMAL(9, 2)) / 60 <= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as within_10_minutes,
       . . .
FROM tblCAD 
WHERE [AO-NonPublicEvent] = 1 AND
      [Reporting Exclusions] = 0 AND
      [Reporting Priority] = '1'     
GROUP BY [Financial Year];
```

Note that you should fix your column names so they don't need to be escaped.  I would suggest something like `Fiscal_Year`, `AO_NonPublic_Event`, `Reporting_Exclusions`, and so on.

I'm also not sure why you are multiplying the first count by 100.  And the above assumes that `[Event Number]` is not `NULL`.  If that is the case, then you need to take that into account.

Comment: you are awesome! I was obviously way to close to this and was significantly over complicating it. Agree with your comments for naming conventions, though unfortunately this is somewhat complex databased and is largely out of my control. I also must have missed removing the *100, as this was originally a division query. THANK YOU!!